# Definition of induction

Tags: real-analysis, induction, recursion

I was reading **principle of recursive definition** from Toplogy by **James R. munkres**. And there i saw a this statement that I can't understand

recursion is something that you define by induction but not prove by induction. My question is what is the definition of  induction then??

Comment: In mathematics one does not generally "prove" a definition.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to summarise the process of induction as two things:

1) The process of induction involves checking the base case for $n$, setting $n = k+1$, and rearranging the expression to prove the case also works for $k+1$.

2) Induction is specifically used for **integers only**. It is strong for proofs only involving integers, as you can repetitively define $k+1$ as $k$ to get $k+2, k+3...$ and so on. However, many problems in all fields of algebra (in my experience) use rational numbers (that are fractions), irrational numbers, complex numbers, and so is a "weaker" method of proof.

Comment: Induction is not defined b

Comment: Corrected the mistake.